# Accessing a search engine database from react native app

Tags: database, react-native, search-engine

I am creating a food logging app. I would like to implement a feature where once you log a food item and the amount of the food item, the app goes out and finds values like cholesterol, carbs, protein, fat, and more on search engines or some database that has this information. What is the best way to approach this? Do I need to make a database with all these values, or is there an easier way to access a search engine's database? I am using react native with Expo to build my app. Please let me know your best recommendations! Thank you.

Comment: hello provide the site , let me see is that possible to get details from that search engine as we want or not,

Comment: What do you think about this site? https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/

Comment: Dear , at the begginging you need to go as specific as you can for mining data from that site,then for the site you sent 
the name of nutrition is within ``` <span _ngcontent-c6="" name="finalFoodNutrientName">Energy</span> ``` you can grab it by a little bit trick.also you can find all other stuff as i mention